# Global Variables in ReactJS

Tags: reactjs, global-variables

We're currently working on a school project and we have a part of the app that's kind of "external". (Just used for displaying a graph)
So that /graph folder is now in the /src folder and when compiling the react app we get tons of import errors.
Is there a way to bypass those imports and just use the global variables, which are already implemented?

Comment: Webpack `ProvidePlugin` sounds like a good fit for defining a bunch of globals. https://webpack.js.org/plugins/provide-plugin/

Comment: Also check webpack `externals` https://webpack.js.org/configuration/externals/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Global variables in React can be implemented using webpack.config.js file.

Inside the webpack config file declare your global variable.

i.e. `const API_URL = JSON.stringify('http://api:8080');` Also, you need to add new plugins to webpack, in order for this global variable to be accessible by your whole app.

```
new webpack.DefinePlugin({ //defining gloabl variable
        API_URL,
});
```

But global variable aside if just want to get rid of the component and module import error, then you can simply set aliases for those in your `.babelrc` file. This way, you do not need to write `'../../..something'`, you can just write `'something'`.

```
{
"presets": ["react", "es2015", "stage-0"],

"plugins": [
    ["module-resolver", {
      "root": ["./src"],
      "alias": {
        "src": "/",
        "components": "/components",
        "actions": "/actions",
        "containers": "/containers",
        "images": "/images",
        "reducers": "/reducers",
        "styles": "/styles",
        "utils": "/utils",
      }
    }]
]
}}
```

This is a sample `.babelrc` file with alias for components and other folders. Now from any where in the app if I write `import { Something } from 'components/Something'`, my app will know where to find it. No need to write `'../../../components/Something'`

Answer (score 0):

It is not recomended to use global variables, but you can simply use window object to save variables, for example window.myGlobalVar = 3. In addition, you can use react context.

Answer (score 0):

You can try this:

Parent.js

```
var myVar = {}

class MyComponent extends Component {

...
...
myVar = new Object();
...
...
render() {
   return <div>
                 \\ children
                 <MyLeftBranch myVar={myVar} />
                 <MyRightBranch myVar={myVar} />
              </div>
}
}

export default MyComponent;
```

child.js

```
class Child extends Component {
     { myVar } = this.props;
     \\use myVar
}
```